# OData null parameter on Post method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a simple ASP.NET WebApi ODataV4 controller -

```
public class FooController : ODataController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody] Foo fooObj)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Foo model is as below and Foo is defined as an EntityType in the EDM model -

```
public class
{
    [Key]
    string id {get ; set;}

    string name {get; set;}
}
```

I generated ODataClient for this model and trying to Post a new Foo object -

```
FooContext container = new FooContext(..);
Foo newFoo = new Foo() 
{
      name = "Simple foo"
}
container.AddToFoos(newFoo );
```

When I do this, the 'fooObj' in the Post method is null. However when I set the the 'id' property in the request to a non-null value (even empty string), it seems to work fine -

```
Foo newFoo = new Foo() 
{
      id = "",
      name = "Simple foo"
}
```

Any pointers what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at your $metadata, the key property "id" is non-nullable. During your OData model registration, you should be able to set it to optional. I had a similar issue but I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v7.0.1. I'm not sure what version of OData you are using but the way I did this was during the building of my model:

```
builder.EntityType<Foo>().Property(p => p.Id).IsOptional();
```